# Adding variable amount of values, based on numeric values

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, array-formulas

**Problem Solved**

Cheesy Mistake... lol

For my time column when i was using my milliseconds i was using the column in my sheet that i was not mentioning. I was using my millisecond interval column. I thought this would work, but forgot that my new formula was based on the specific time, not the interval of time since this last thing was seen. So the sum was always less than 60000. Thanks for all your help and wish i could accept two answers. =)

**Revisiting the whole question**

Below are some of my actual values. I was using seconds earlier, but in my real document i am using milliseconds. I need the sumoflist column to be the sum of minorsums that are 60 seconds old from the current time. This would be 60000 milliseconds.

Here is the EXACT formula that i was using from earlier. And yes, i was entering it correctly and it was still not working. I had to modify it a little so that it would work with my sheet and milliseconds.

```
{=SUM(IF($B2-$B$2:$B2<60000,$U$2:$U2))}
{=COUNT(IF($B2-$B$2:$B2<60000,$U$2:$U2))}
```

The summing function will sum all of them, no matter how old they are. The same for the counting.

Since i gave you small chunk of the data, use 20000 for examples. Thanks to all those that have helped me so far! And please continue helping me! <3

---

```
// csv for easy import
seconds,sumoflist,minorsums
800,0,0
1000,40000,40000
1200,80000,40000
1000,120000,40000
800,160000,40000
1000,200000,40000
800,240000,40000
1000,280000,40000
1200,320000,40000
1000,360000,40000
800,400000,40000
1000,440000,40000
800,480000,40000
1000,520000,40000
1200,560000,40000
1000,600000,40000
800,640000,40000
1000,680000,40000
800,720000,40000
1000,760000,40000
1200,800000,40000
1000,840000,40000
800,880000,40000
1000,920000,40000
800,960000,40000
1000,1000000,40000
1200,1040000,40000
1000,1080000,40000
800,1120000,40000
1000,1160000,40000
800,1200000,40000
1000,1240000,40000
800,1280000,40000
850,1282500,2500
900,1285000,2500
850,1287500,2500
```

Comment: Which column do you want calculated? Is it Sumoflist? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Do you want a macro function, or a formular in the cells of the columns?

I am trying to help you if I can. Would you please post 10 to 20 lines of the data as an example?

Comment: +1 for question not clear. Explain what you have and what you want to have. Examples are very welcome.

Comment: Your answer should be a comment

Comment: I believe P hasn't enough rep to comment...

Comment: I do think so. Because I do not see "comment" under the above post. But I want to help if I can. And I will have "enough" rep :)

Comment: More detail added, sorry for the lack there of.

Comment: More detail added, sorry for the lack there of. @pdotwang, either one is fine, as long as it gets the job done. Gave you a +1 to help you get your comment privileges.

Comment: @prolink007, the last four entries for sumoflist don't fit your description, shouldn't they be 320000, 360000, 400000 and 362500?

Comment: @Lance Roberts: fixed. @everyone: How can i get the number of values that are in that 60 second interval? I need it so i can get the sqrt of the average of the sumoflist. THANKS!

Comment: You can use the COUNT function instead of the SUM.

Comment: The proposed solutions are not working the way i needed them too upon second look. I need it to sum "minorsums" that are within 60 seconds of the current "time". Please assist me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @prolink007, what do you mean by within? Both forward and backward? So a 120 second interval?

Comment: @prolink007, see the new edit.

Comment: Major revision to OP, please help and thanks to those who have helped me so far!!

Comment: I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525377/excel-line-chart-question   If you think you might be able to help me with it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first cell (next to `0`), type in

```
=SUM(IF((A:A<=A2)*(A:A>A2-60),C:C,0))
```

and press **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** to confirm(, and there will be `{}` around the formula after you have done so).

Then drag down.

---

[image]

Here you see, the answers provided by Excellll and me are both correct.

For `61.6`, `1.8` - `61.6` are summed, while for `63.25`, `4` - `63.25` are summed.

To make sure, the `{` and `}` are around the formula, which appear after CTRL + ALT + ENTER.

That is, press CTRL and hold, press ALT and hold, press ENTER and release 3 simultaneously.

Comment: What exactly is that formula you posted supposed to do? It is not giving me the correct results.

Comment: Your function gives me the sum of the whole column. I am wanting ONLY the sum of the values in the column 'minorsums' that are within a 60 second time interval from the current 'time' value. So, if the time value is older than 60 seconds from the current time value, the current 'minorsums' value is not part of that sum anymore.

Comment: @prolink007, you didn't enter the formula as an array formula.  Follow @Dante Jiang's instructions, and it should work fine (but slowly).  When you paste the formula into B2, hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just pressing Enter.

Comment: The proposed solutions are not working the way i needed them too upon second look. I need it to sum "minorsums" that are within 60 seconds of the current "time". Please assist me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Major revision to OP, please help and thanks to those who have helped me so far!!

Comment: @prolink007, so.... change `60` to `60000` is sufficient.... What is your actual problem? `{` and `}` are **not typed**, but **appear** after using CTRL + ALT + ENTER.

Comment: Yes, that is the way it is happening and it is still not working.

Comment: @prolink007, but it is working on my computer, and I assume it is also working on Excellll's.

Comment: @prolink007, have you noticed the green triangles in my snapshot for Excellll's answer? Excel notices me some kind of error by that, and if I tell Excel to correct the error, Excel will sum them all. I think that is the problem. You may use my answer, it works without prompts for errors.

Comment: When i click update error, the formula turns into this and is worse: =SUM(IF($B3-$B$2:$B681<60000,$U$2:$U3))

Comment: @prolink007, do not click update error. The one before updated is the right one.

Comment: But it is still not working... =( Thanks for all the help you are giving, by the way.

Comment: It seems to be working when i use "seconds" instead of milliseconds. The only thing i change is the column the formula points at and the value it is testing for: Original: "=SUM(IF($A2-$A$2:$A2<60,$U$2:$U2))" New: "=SUM(IF($B2-$B$2:$B2<60000,$U$2:$U2))"

Comment: I figured it out!! I used the Evaluate Formula thing in excel. I will post my findings. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @prolink007, how can you use that in the first place.... OK. Happy to see it is solved at last....

Comment: For my time column when i was using my milliseconds i was using the column in my sheet that i was not mentioning. I was using my millisecond interval column. I thought this would work, but forgot that my new formula was based on the specific time, not the interval of time since this last thing was seen. So the sum was always less than 60000. Thanks for all your help and wish i could accept two answers. =)

Comment: I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525377/excel-line-chart-question   If you think you might be able to help me with it too.

Answer (score 2):

Dante Jiang's suggestion is right, but the full column references slow down the calculation considerably.  Try this instead:

```
=SUM(IF($A2-$A$2:$A2<60,$C$2:$C2))
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter the formula as an array formula.  Then fill down.

Comment: How can i get the number of values that are in that 60 second interval? I need it so i can get the sqrt of the average of the sumoflist. THANKS!

Comment: @Excellll: what do the question marks do? Sorry for the noob question, trying to learn some of these formulas so i do not have to ask questions any more. Thanks in advance, also take a look at my above comment.

Comment: The '$' fixes the row or column reference.  A regular cell reference like "A1" is relative to the cell in which it appears.  For instance, if you put "=A1" in cell E1, and then fill down to E2, the formula in E2 will be "=A2".  If instead you fix the row reference with "=A$1", the formula in E2 will also be "=A$1".  Same goes for filling over and fixing the column reference.

Comment: With regard to your second question, Lance Roberts is right.  Use the same formula with COUNT instead of SUM.

Comment: Actually this is not working the way i need it too. I need it to ONLY sum the values in "C" that are within 60 seconds of the current "time" in the "A" column. It is summing them all currently. Please assist if you can again. Thanks

Comment: If the formula isn't showing up with brackets like this {...}, the formula isn't entered as an array formula.  Do the following, and be careful not to disturb the changes afterward.   1. Select B2 (the top cell of 'sumoflist'.  2. Click inside the formula bar.  3. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.  This should make the formula in B2 show up inside the set brackets.  4. Fill down B2 to the rest of the column.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am doing. It is summing all of the list... i only need it to sum the values that are associated with time that is within 60 seconds of the current value in the time column. 60 seconds back in time.

Comment: Major revision to OP, please help and thanks to those who have helped me so far!!

Comment: For my time column when i was using my milliseconds i was using the column in my sheet that i was not mentioning. I was using my millisecond interval column. I thought this would work, but forgot that my new formula was based on the specific time, not the interval of time since this last thing was seen. So the sum was always less than 60000. Thanks for all your help and wish i could accept two answers. =)

Comment: I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525377/excel-line-chart-question   If you think you might be able to help me with it too.